# GetApplicationConext() error

Tags: android, gps

So today I started reading on tutorials on how to get my current GPS location using Android studio. but I came up with an error " Error:(21, 24) error: cannot find symbol method getApplicationContext()  "  I have looked around stuckoverflow but none of the solutions worked for me. here is the code

```
 package com.example.chara.usegps;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by charalambous on 11/9/2015.
 */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
            String Text = "My Current Location is: " + " Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() + "longitude = " + location.getLongitude();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your class is not `extend`ed from `Activity`Class. you must add a `Context` object to your `Costructor` method and use it as `context`.

Comment: yeah that seemed to have worked. thanks a lot ..
but why do i keep getting downvoted for a simple question? is really the community of this website so hostile ?

Comment: you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228358/why-my-questions-on-stackoverflow-are-getting-downvotes-without-explanation)

Comment: so to get this clear. I should just post like I get this error: example error..  
here is the code 
example code

Like that for example ? I have seen the how to ask a question. and I thought i followed it

Comment: @user3656666:this website is one of the best references for programming questions. I do not think there is any need to ask question for a novice programmer because he\she can find his\her answer with searching in community.

Comment: @karimkhan I cant understand what you are trying to say my friend. but if what I understood is correct I would have to disagree with you on this manner =) but this is not a place to talk about this have a nice day

Comment: I mean you can create a Constructor method for class and inside it initialize your Context and use it inside class. i am very clear.

Comment: ahha. but i think this website with more than 2800000 visit per day(rank 57 in world) can be a good reference for a novice programmer and there is not need to any question asking.